# How to bind Xamarin Forms Images to a view model?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, imagesource

If I have an image in iOS **Assets.xcassets** called "foo" and I want to assign it to a bound property in a view model that is consumed by this XAML ...

```cs
<Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}" />
```

What do I need to do in the view model to make it load correctly?

I have tried setting the property to `ImageSource.FromFile("foo")`.
I also tried `ImageSource.FromFile("foo.png")`.
And I tried `ImageSource.FromResource("foo.png")`.
Finally, since `ImageSource` seems to overload assignment directly from `string`, I tried just assigning an `ImageSource` the string value ("foo").

None of these approaches seems to actually load the image from the assets.

Assigning is directly in XAML, however, works:

```cs
<Image Source="foo" />
```

Is anyone knowledgeable in how images can be bound to a view model?

**[EDIT]**

The reason, apparently, is because the view model I bind to is actually a sub view model (a property in the page's BindingContext). If I move the source properties to the root BindingContext it works.

Is there some hard coded stuff going on in the binding engine that needs to treat ImageSource values differently?

[Here's a link to a small sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bg48nup5enuyzvl/Spike.DynamicImage.zip?dl=0) if you like to try it out.

Comment: Have you tried binding it to a string?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "I tried just assigning an ImageSource the string value ("foo")."

Comment: Didn't read that part. And dos your viewmodel implement INotify? With raisingpropertychanged for the bindings?

Comment: Is MyImageSource a property with a public getter?

Comment: Also you might want to try using compiled bindings to get compile time error messages [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings). By the way does any other binding work in this view/viemodel?

Comment: Yes, the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property have a publig getter.

Comment: Can you post your ViewModel, and the structure of your images?

Comment: @MaxHampton: Yes, assigning a string literal as the source works fine. Try assigning "foo.png" to a property in the BindingContext and bind the image's Source property to it instead (to dynamically change the image at runtime). Does it also work?

Comment: I can pull together a small demo project and upload it. Give me a few minutes ...

Comment: Seems I must've taken a wrong turn somewhere. I pulled together a small demo app to show off the problem but it turns out I cannot repro it. It works fine binding an Image.Source to `string` or an `ImageSource` (assigned with `ImageSource.FromFile()`). Now I need to figure out what's different in the app  I'm writing. 

Thanks for taking the time guys!

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Comment: I didn't really resolve it. But I found out what's going on, and it's pretty "interesting". The difference is that in the app I write the view model I bind the images to is itself part of another view model, which is the page's `BindingContext`. For some reason it works fine if the image sources reside in the root view model but not if they reside in a sub view model. Might be some under-the-hood hard coding going on in XAML to resolve ImageSource type of bindings that can't cope with hierarchical view models.

Comment: Here's a sample project if you're interested. I'll see if I can figure it out. If not, it's a pretty serious limitation if you're into MVVM.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bg48nup5enuyzvl/Spike.DynamicImage.zip?dl=0